# Gridview with Textbox and Textchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am added to my gridview textbox inside RowDataBound and added TextChanged for each textbox. When I write inside textbox some text, firing work for all textbox inside gridview. How to solve this is the problem? Column with textbox called CommentTS.[image: My gridview inside another gridview]

Code how I adding a textbox to gridview.

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
tb.CssClass = "form-control";
tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
tb.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[i].Text).ToString();
tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextCommentUpdate);
tb.AutoPostBack = true;
e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(tb);
```

Comment: tb.ID = e.Row.Cells[0].Text; is not Cell at zero location, please first fix it ..

Comment: This is a need for update comment in table SQL.

Comment: Solved problem via js.